# How important is roof felt in terms of keeping the house dry?

Tags: roof, roofing

There are multiple rips in the roofing felt of my home to the point the roofing felt doesn't really exist towards the end of the roof area in large places.  The roofing felt is in poor condition but everything else looks to be in good condition (I can see some of the battens).  How urgent would this job be to fix?

Comment: Why do you see roof felt? It's supposed to be under your shingles. Read about its importance here: https://gilstraproofing.com/why-roofing-felt-is-important/. In short, it's a backup mechanism so that any water which gets under your shingles does not wreak havoc inside your home. You should add a picture.

Comment: Pictures will help.  What we imagine as roof felt might be different for you.  If I saw that I would be looking to get a new roof yesterday.

Comment: A roofer has removed the tiles to take a look.  The wooden battens, joists, nails etc don't seem to be rotten but the felt is severely damaged.  I'll add a picture later.  By roofing felt I mean the felt that goes under the tiles, under the tile battens and above the roof joists.

Comment: If the tiles have already been removed to inspect it, why not spend $50 for a roll of felt and replace it while you have it open? The labor is the expensive part, and you're already paying for that.

Comment: Considering that this is something which you cannot fix without tearing everything off again, just do it now while it's all accessible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The felt is there to stop wind, and snow driven by it, ending up in the attic/loft. Without it, on a bad day, the weather can end up inside the house, taking a long time to dry out, causing all sorts of extra damage.

Difficult without a picture and knowledge of location, but basically needs replacing somehow.